# Why Isn't Metadata Part of a Git SHA-1 Hash?

Tags: git, file, github

Since `git` does not track metadata for files, that means that file metadata is not part of the `SHA-1` hash for a file. It seems like this should be part of the SHA-1 hash for a file?

Why doesn't the hash of a file change if the file name or some other metadata for that file changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file in git is represented by two parts

1. a blob of its contents
2. a directory entry in the file tree

Things like file names are stored in the tree.

If you rename a file (and commit), you will get a new tree that is still pointing to the same content blob.

Conversely, you can have multiple files (of the same content) point to the same blob.

Comment: Why doesn't changing a filename change the SHA-1 hash and make git see the file as different? Git won't see any difference unless I tell it that it was renamed with `git mv`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Changing a filename does not modify the contents of the file, so the SHA-1 hash remains the same. Also, changing a filename without adding the rename operation to the index (which is what `git mv` does, but there are other ways to do it) does not let git know that you now want to track the "new" file (and stop tracking the "old" file).

Comment: So the SHA-1 hash isn't based on the filename, only the file contents?

Comment: The SHA-1 hash for the file's content is based only on the file contents. The SHA-1 hash for the directory tree entry is based on the file names (and other meta data) of all files (and subdirectories) in the directory.

Comment: Why doesn't git register the change automatically if I change a filename since SHA-1 has for the tree entry should change. Everything I've read says that git doesn't track the metadata such as filenames.

Comment: Git doesn't automatically register the change of a file's content or the creation or the deletion of a file, either. You have to `git add` all of these things. That way you have complete control over what you are trying to commit.